# Increase quantity when adding same Option

Tags: php, oop, shopping-cart

I have managed to implement OOP of `Cart` Basket

An Item contain 1 or more options.

If I add same OptionID again then the number of quantity should increase rather than creating another `Option` Object.  How can that be done?

If I add same ItemID again, it should refuse to create another `Item` object.

Also is my OOP is good?

```
    class Cart {

        public $item = array();

        public function addItem($id) {
            $item = new Item();
            $item->setItem($id);
            $this->item[] = $item;
            return $item;
        }

    }

    class Item {

        private $id = array();
        private $option = array();

        public function setItem($id) {
            $this->id = $id;
            return $this;
        }

        public function addOption($id) {
            $option = new Option();
            $option->setOption($id);
            $this->option[] = $option;
        }

    }

    class Option {

        private $quantity;
        private $id;

        public function setOption($id) {
            $this->quantity = 1;
            $this->id = $id;
            return $this;
        }

    }
    $cart = new Cart();

    //ItemID 10
    $item = $cart->addItem(10);

    //OptionID
    $item->addOption(11);
    $item->addOption(22);
    $item->addOption(22); //should increase quantity

   //It should not create another object because we already have Item Object of ItemID10
   $item = $cart->addItem(10); 

    $Shop = $cart;

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($Shop);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partialy rewrote the code and tested:

```
<?php
class Cart {

        public $items = array();

        public function addItem($id) {
            if(array_key_exists($id, $this->items)){
                $item = $this->items[$id];
            }else{
                $item = new Item($id);
                $this->items[$id] = &$item;
            } 
            return $item;
        }

    }

    class Item {

        private $id;
        private $options = array();

        public function __construct($id) {
            $this->id = $id;
            return $this;
        }

        public function addOption($id) {
            if(array_key_exists($id, $this->options)){
                $this->options[$id]->addQuantity();
            }else{
                $option = new Option($id);
                $this->options[$id] = $option;
            }           
        }

    }

    class Option {

        private $quantity;
        private $id;

        public function __construct($id) {
            $this->quantity = 1;
            $this->id = $id;
            return $this;
        }

        public function addQuantity()
        {
            $this->quantity++;
        }
    }

    $cart = new Cart();

    //ItemID 10
    $item = $cart->addItem(10);

    //OptionID
    $item->addOption(11);
    $item->addOption(22);
    $item->addOption(22); //should increase quantity

   //It should not create another object because we already have Item Object of ItemID10
   $item = $cart->addItem(10); 

    $Shop = $cart;

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($Shop);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for example, I have tried it and did not increase the quantity. There is no error though.

Comment: The post I had before this told him how to fix it but he didn't got it to work so that is why I rewrote it. A well, I don't really care about -1. I helped someone so I am happy ^^

Answer (score 1):

If you can have only one item with the unique id in the cart - then rewrite the addItem() method like this:

```
 public function addItem($id) {
        $result = false;

        if (empty($this->item[$id])) {
            $item = new Item();
            $item->setItem($id);
            $this->item[$id] = $item;

            $result = $item;
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

The same is with addOption() method:

```
public function addOption($id) {
        if (empty($this->option[$id])) {
            $option = new Option();
            $option->setOption($id);
            $this->option[$id] = $option;
        }
        else {
            $this->option[$id]->setQuantity($this->option[$id]->getQuantity() + 1);
        }
    }
```

And of course you should implement setQuantity() and getQuantity() methods in Option class.
Hope this helps.